# maven shade plugin seems not to use classifier name

Tags: maven

When I create a jar file with maven and use profiles with a classifier, the shaded jar file does not have the classifier in the name.

Maven version: Apache Maven 3.2.5

Here is one of the profiles:

```
    <profile>
        <id>external</id>
        <properties>
            <envClassifier>external</envClassifier>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>external</classifier>
                            </configuration>
                            <id>external-package</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                               <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                               </goals>
                          </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

However, the target jar files are not named as I expected (you can see the large shaded jar @111MB doesn't have the classified name of 'external':

- 363 KB  original-myjar-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- 111 MB  myjar-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- 362 KB  myjar-0.1-SNAPSHOT-external.jar

Here is my shading configuration:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <createDependencyReducedPom>true
              </createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <relocations>
                  ---removed
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

I could use shadedArtifactId to force the name of the output file but it seems like that shouldn't be needed.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

From my experience, the shade plugin takes the primary artifact and replaces it with the shaded one.

If you want the shaded artifact to have a classifier, you should add these configurations to the shade plugin:

```
<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
<shadedClassifierName>external</shadedClassifierName>
```

It's not clear to me why you need the profiles or the additional jar plugin configuration with the classifier.  I think you can just use the shade plugin to generate the classified jar that you want.  Clarify if there is some requirement forcing you to use profiles.

Answer (score -1):

So I was able to get this working by using the finalName property.  Would be curious to here if others use this technique or if there are other solutions.

```
   <profile>
      <id>external</id>
      <properties>
        <envClassifier>internal</envClassifier>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-external</finalName>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: Are you sure this actually installs & deploys the shaded JAR with the desired classifier? AFAIK, the `finalName` won’t affect the `groupId:artifactId:packaging:classifier:version` under which your file will be installed in the local repository or deployed to a remote repository. Thus, other Maven builds won’t be able to find it with a classifier of `external`. Have a good look at the output of `install:install` to see whether my suspicion is correct. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious. Where does the above go?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 profiles go inside the `profiles` tag. If you do not have a `profiles` tag, simply add it inside the root tag `project`. I usually put them after `build` tag close to the end of the file